# Common home folder for Windows 8 and Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: windows-8, ubuntu-13.04

I want to make a common home folder for both Windows 8 and Ubuntu 13.04
My Windows "Windows(C)" Drive is NTFS where home folder is in Users\XYZ\Documents

My question is **how to make Documents in Nautilus make me display contents of Documents in Windows documents folder**?

Windows(C) is mounted in Ubuntu as \media\Windows\

I please don't want a dropbox sync or Bookmark the Windows documents location.

Answer (score 2):

First thing: You cannot use the same home folder for both operating systems. This is easily, because Windows and Linux need different file systems, which provide different permission systems, to work.

You can however use your Windows documents folder as your Ubuntu documents folder.

To do this:

- Find out the location of your Windows Documents folder.
- Delete your original Ubuntu Documents folder
- Create a [symbolic link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) from the location of your Linux Documents folder to your Windows documents folder

The last step can be done by calling

```
ln -s /media/windows/Users/XYZ/Documents ~/Documents
```

from a shell.

Note that you use `/` instead of `\` in Linux and that Linux is case sensitive. Spaces must be escaped (`\`).